# Email showing arrow symbols

Tags: email, joomla

We are using Joomla and when it sends emails out it works fine except that in place of doing line feeds we are getting the arrow symbol (⏎).
Within the email we have \n\n - how would we get rid of the symbols.

Cheers
Rich

Comment: What component are you using the e-mails? Or are you referring to the registrations e-mails? If it's a component, have you contacted the developer?

Comment: Can you show the code, where message is sent?

Comment: Hi, 
Here is a snippet of the code 
$msg .= JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_MESSAGE_SUBJECT' ) . " : " . $subject . "\n"; 
$msg .= JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_CATEGORY' ) . " : " . $this->getCategory()->name . "\n"; $msg .= JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_VIEW_POSTED' ) . " : " . $this->getAuthor()->getName('???', false) . "\n\n"; $msg .= "URL : $url\n\n"; if ($config->mailfull == 1) 
{ $msg .= JText::_ ( 'COM_KUNENA_MESSAGE' ) . " :\n-----\n"; 
$msg .= $message; 
$msg .= "\n-----\n\n"; } 
$msg .= $msg2 . "\n"; 

We are getting this character ⏎ at the end of each line. Thanks – PerryW